# Webform element validation custom module

Tags: 8, forms

I want to add a custom validation to text input, I followed the instruction provided in
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook/how-to-add-custom-validation-to-a-webform-element

I have a requirement which needs to verify an id entered into a text box, by making a REST API call to another system, the issue  is to make that REST API call, I need another text parameter which is also inputed into the webform. 
I have written a custom handler which makes that rest call, but that custom handler work on webform post save option only, how can I pass more than 2 fields to the validate function mentioned in the example given.

```
function onboarding_webform_element_alter(array &$element, FormStateInterface $form_state, array $context) {
    // check for desired element   
   if (isset($element['#webform_id']) && $element['#webform_id'] === 'register_account--surname'){
     $surname= $element['#default_value'];
    $form_state->setValue('SOME_NAME', $surname);    
   }  
   if (isset($element['#webform_id']) && $element['#webform_id'] === 'register_account--proda_id') {

        $element['#element_validate'][] = array(
            'Drupal\dhs_vendor_onboarding\Validate\DhsValidateConstraint',
            'validate'
        );      
    } 
}
```

In the validate function:

```
public static function validate(array &$element, FormStateInterface $formState, array &$form) {
        ksm($formState->getValue('SOME_NAME'));
        $webformKey = $element['#webform_key'];       
        $value = $formState->getValue($webformKey);
        $surname= $formState->getValue('SOME_NAME');
        }
```

I am not getting any value for surname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to get the value of surname from the Formstate, the form state had surname in surname field itself.

```
public static function validate(array &$element, FormStateInterface $formState, array &$form) {      
    $webformKey = $element['#webform_key'];       
    $value = $formState->getValue($webformKey);
    $surname= $formState->getValue('surname');
}
```

this did the trick.